# Where did the masquerade ball come from and what was its original concept?

Tags: everyday-life, fashion, tradition

I mean a kind of party which guests and hosts hide their faces behind different masks or/and wear odd clothes. Surely there is no certain idea about main concept with me unless perhaps it has roots in customs and traditions or religions like Halloween religious roots.

Comment: A trivial search on google or wikipedia will reveal answers.   Halloween is not a religion.

Comment: I searched it but only one sentence in wiki about its origin not the main concept and surely I didn't write Halloween is a religion but has roots in religion. By a trivial search in google you can find it.

Comment: Religious roots of Halloween: https://www.google.com/search?q=halloween+roots+in+religion&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a. It is about Halloween but Halloween is one of masquerade ball parties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer appears to be the Venetian Republic was the first nation to hold masquerade balls.

[Wikipedia has an article on the history of masquerade](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masquerade_ball&ei=ioRVUY2uONPC4AOZ9YH4Cw&usg=AFQjCNHIMtOX6b233hIRW4gaa507-N-Giw&sig2=NcpIY-aLPO19Pda0cKq1xA&bvm=bv.44442042,d.dmg)

[Victorian Masquerade Ball](http://www.victoriaball.com/history.html) confirms many of the assertions in wikipedia

[Samantha Peach](http://www.samanthapeachmasks.com/masquerade-ball-history.html) has an article that is less well sourced